# Bluetooth scanner app don't yield results

Tags: bluetooth

I have a OnePlus One with Cyanogen based on Android 6.0.1 as well as an old Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 with stock Android 4.x.
In addition, there is a TV with Bluetooth, and one of this modern Bluetooth speakers.

Both of my Android devices list the three other devices in its Bluetooth menu.

Now, I've tried out several bluetooth scanner apps like

- [BLE Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macdom.ble.blescanner)
- [Bluetooth LE Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.alt236.btlescan)
- [Bluetooth Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.WisdomStar.BtScan)
- [Bluetooth 4.0 Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluemotionlabs.bluescan)

but none of them lists any bluetooth devices. The last one crashes my phone...
May be, the first two scan for BLE devices only, but the last two seem to scan for both.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

(I'd like to get the RSSI to evaluate if it is suitable for a special problem at work, and naively thought each scanner could simply provide it.)

---

**EDIT:**
The phone is running Cyanogen 13.1.2.
GPS is on, and the apps have granted permission to access bluetooth and GPS.

I also thought there may be a problem with my phone, but it's exactly the same with my tablet.

And as said, the phone as well as the tablet do list the TV and the speaker in their menu, can connect to them, and play music etc. It's just that the BT scanner apps just list nothing.

(By the way: Many scanners want GPS to link bluetooth devices to position, but why is GPS needed to detect bluetooth devices?)

---

**EDIT 2:**

Because my problem drives me nuts, I just wrote my own Android Bluetooth scanner. Before giving it GPS access, it doesn't list anything, but after, it just works.
It's quite interesting, from the apps listed above only two want GPS access...

Oh, and no idea yet why exactly GPS is needed, but the API just requests it.

Comment: What's the Cyanogenmod version number? If several apps are behaving the same way, most likely it is a bug in the ROM. Also, don't forget you need to allow the location permission for the app to see any devices.